# D3 js function comes back undefined

Tags: javascript, function, d3.js, undefined

I want to make this into a function:

```
var meanPoints = d3.mean(data, function(d) {return d['total points'] });
console.log(meanPoints);
```

This works and gives me the mean of the total point of my json file.
But if i try to make a function like so:

```
function meanVak(vak) {
d3.mean(data, function(d) {return d [vak] });
}

var meanPoints = meanVak('total points');
console.info(meanPoints);
```

It comes back as undefined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you don't have `return` statement:

```
function meanVak(vak) {
    return d3.mean(data, function(d) {return d [vak] });
}
```

Side note: by default functions without `return` statement return `undefined`.